# Customizable Sidebar - How to split components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm currently working on a sidebar component. This sidebar contains multiple cards, like one with input and a list, one with input and buttons and one with only buttons. Now it should be as   modifiable as possible. I thought of passing arrays with the needed types and labels in a card to the sidebar component.

So for a view like in the first card:

[image: Sidebar]

It could be like this:

```
    const data=[
        {
            label:"Systems",
            type: "heading"
        },
        {
            label:"",
            type: "input",
            onChange: "search"
        },
        {
            label: "",
            type: "ul",
            elements: [
                "Item#1",
                "Item#2",
                "Item#3",
                "Item#4",
            ]
        }
    ]

    <Sidebar card={data} />
```

I don't know if it's better style to do it like this and have a hard time processing all possibilites or better just focus on these hardcoded layouts and let them fill with data (i did this with ~6 types of other `card`-elements before).
Or is there a completely other way to create customizable elements like this?

Comment: Since you will have more than one card, "<Sidebar card={data} />" should be replaced with something like "<Sidebar>{cards.map(card => <MyCardComponent data={card} />)}</Sidebar>". But this is a very broad question, and I doubt that it will be answered in full here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding why you have "onChange", "type" and other things as your data? Are you trying to create a web builder system?

Comment: Now that you mention it, yeah its kind of a web builder. I guess i go with the pre-defined approach.